# '_AxesStack' object is not callable while using networkx to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, networkx

Following one of online tutorials I found it difficult to run even a small piece of paragraph.
Here is what I want to write into the graph: a Directed acyclic unweighted matrix into the graph, however I encountered the problem of matrix-representing and pic-representing. The former gives a warning and substitutes output matrix with arrays. However the pic plotting is always output only errors I don't know why. Here is my code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0,1,1,0],
              [1,0,1,1],
              [1,1,0,0],
              [0,1,0,0]])
G=nx.from_numpy_array(A)
nx.draw(G,with_lables=True)
```

And my networkx version is 2.8.4, matplotlib version is 3.6.0, matching the versions tutorial mentioned.
Here is the error:

```
'_AxesStack' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 34):

Start using

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
```

instead of

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?

Answer (score 7):

The argument that [`draw()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) supports is `with_labels`. Please fix your typo.

The error has been discussed on [`this`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5798) thread of networkx's GitHub repository, and suggests users with matplotlib 3.6.0rc1 to update networkx to its latest version.

With the fixed typo, and networkx version 2.8.7 and matplotlib version 3.5.1, the code produces following figure:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Please consider [this answer from Mohamad Sobhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75200324/7789963) if you are using networkx v3.1, and do not wish to downgrade Matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion! After I degrade my matplotlib package to 3.5.1, the error vanished. However, there are still two questions. The first one is that whether the picture can only be shown in jupyternotebook? When use the pycharm, I can only see the programme run successfully, but with no picture. The second one is that when I click into "file->settings->Python Interpreter" the latest version shown is 2.8.4, no 2.8.7. Is that the problem of pycharm or anaconda or some other things?

Comment: Actually I want to vote your answer, but sadly the website showed me I can only vote after I've gained 15 points. Pity but appreciated

Comment: @LeonhartDreyse You can update both packages (matplotlib and networkx) - I think you won't get the error with the latest versions. Also, I didn't create this figure in Jupyter Notebook - directly using a .py script. Is there any reason why you are using Python 2.x version? This answer was created using Python 3.9.13.

Comment: Or did you mean to say Pycharm is showing networkx v2.8.4 and not v2.8.7?

Comment: Yeah, Pycharm plugin only shows v2.8.4 the latest. And my python version is also the 3rd, don't know why no picture but only "exit 0", which means no bugs. But nothing showed.

Comment: @LeonhartDreyse Could you please clarify the details by editing the question? That way, we'll get to know all the details in one shot: please include all the things you have tried and what's not working still. :)

Comment: sure. I'm on it

Comment: Downgrading matplotlib==3.5.1 solved the issue!

Answer (score 5):

The error is related to a deprecated feature of matplotlib. The problem is occurred because you are running networkx version 2.8.4. (The most recent stable version of networkx now is ver. 3.0.0).

Based on your explanation, I suppose you're using the conda environment, which you can find at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/networkx. The most recent version is still 2.8.4.

I think the solution for your problem are.

1. Remove the networkx package from your conda environment (conda uninstall networkx)
2. Instead of using conda install, use pip install (pip install networkx)
3. Verify that your current networkx version is now ver 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have rep to comment directly on @medium-dimensional. But check if you're managing your env in pycharm with conda. After having the same issue realised that latest version through conda still (until the day of this reply) 2.8.4.

My suggestion trying to run

```
conda activate <your env> 
pip install --update networkx
```

pip should catch that you already have the package installed and will update to version 3.0 in that very location

Comment: Why would you mingle with both package managers?