# NetworkX: draw_networkx not drawing labels:, draw results in'_AxesStack' object is not callable

Tags: plot, networkx

Trying to draw two nodes graph with latest version of `networkx-3.0` and latest version of `matplotlib-3.6.3`. Drawing does not show labels on the plot:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, text='foo')
G.add_node(2, text='bar')
G.add_edge(1,2)
print("Node labels: ", nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'text'))
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
>> Node labels:  {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
```

[image]

Shows graph without labels. Why?

And this results in error:

```
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16652\3657615245.py in <module>
----> 1 nx.draw(G)
      2 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw(G, pos, ax, **kwds)
    111     cf.set_facecolor("w")
    112     if ax is None:
--> 113         if cf._axstack() is None:
    114             ax = cf.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 1))
    115         else:

TypeError: '_AxesStack' object is not callable

<Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74189581/2476977) to be helpful regarding the draw function

Comment: Thanks, I have read the post you mention. I have latest versions of matplotlib and networkx and python 3.9.15  - - doesn't help in my case.

Comment: I was just dealing with this error a little bit ago and fixed by upgrading `networkx>=2.8.6` (I was on 2.8.4). There was a bug when upgrading the requirements to `matplotlib==3.6rc1`, [PR #5937](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/5937), [ChangeLog](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/release_2.8.6.html#:~:text=Support%20matplotlb%203.6rc1%20failure%20(%235937)). I see that you have `networkx==3.0.0`, but using Anaconda. Idk if this will change anything, but you might try reinstalling from conda forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question: the nx graph doesn't "know" that you want to look at its text attribute for the label, so it just goes with the initial node name.

Instead, you could pass a relabeled graph into the draw function

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, text='foo')
G.add_node(2, text='bar')
G.add_edge(1,2)
print("Node labels: ", nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'text'))

nx.draw_networkx(nx.relabel_nodes(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'text')), 
                 with_labels=True, node_color = 'orange')
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]